# How to show contact profile and membership details in one Civicrm report?

Tags: civicrm

I had a new profile called "Registration details" for contacts, and the profile fields can be edited in account page.

In my contribution page, membership form is enabled as a sign up form for my members, and the new profile  "Registration details" is included in the form.

I would like to have a report to show a summary of contact details, including  "Registration details" profile, and filter by membership status.

If I'm using Constituent Summary Report, I can get all the contact details summary, but I can't filter the report to show those with active membership only.

If I'm using Membership Details Report, I can filter the membership status accurately, but can't show the new profile fields of "Registration details".

Is there anyway I can configure it so that I can show both contact details and filter by membership status? Or should I make any changes to the profile?

PS: I'm using drupal 7, with CiviCRM 4.4.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Drupal it can often be easier in my non-coding experience, to build a View to provide you with these kind of Reports - happy to provide more pointers if that is the direction you end up going

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to accept the answer. If you haven't committed yet to the area51 for CiviCRM please do so.

Comment: Yes, I had committed. Hope the beta site will be available soon!